# MySQL Views breaking mysqldump command

Tags: mysql, backup, view

While trying to backup all data from a mysql server with `mysqldump` I got this error

> `root@server$ mysqldump -uroot -p --master-data=1 --single-transaction --flush-privileges --routines --triggers --all-databases`
>
> `` mysqldump: Couldn't execute 'SHOW FIELDS FROM `_bare_grantee_grants`': View 'common_schema._bare_grantee_grants' references invalid table(s) or column(s) or function(s) or definer/invoker of view lack rights to use them (1356) ``

I assume this is not a permission issue as I'm a root. (I've looked to questions related to this on this SE but I did find they relate to my issue).

What could be the source of the problem and the solution ?

mysql version is 5.7.33 which was upgraded a couple of weeks ago from 5.6

thanks

Comment: Execute `SHOW CREATE VIEW common_schema._bare_grantee_grants;` then check its datasources - each table and each column - for the presence and data type correctness, and all used functions also, including nested ones. Also check permissions needed for this view and mentioned functions execution and all source tables accessing.

Comment: Well, considering we don't use schema I wonder what broke that. I did `SHOW CREATE VIEW common_schema._bare_grantee_grants;` and executed the query which returned me the same error but pointing to view `sql_grants` itself broken `ERROR 1356 (HY000): View 'common_schema.sql_grants' references invalid table(s) or column(s) or function(s) or definer/invoker of view lack rights to use them` which returns complicated query.
My point is there a way to refresh all the views provided by mysql ?

Comment: Move by this errors chain. Execute `SHOW CREATE VIEW common_schema.sql_grants;` now.. if error occures again then move on.. until the source of the problem 'll be found. Fixing it move back and check all views in a chain.